# Trouble indexing existing collection with Mongoosastic in Keystonejs

Tags: elasticsearch, keystonejs, mongoosastic

I have Mongoosastic working on a few models in Keystone and they update just fine using:

```
Test.schema.plugin(mongoosastic);
```

But when I try the documented way of synchronising/indexing an existing collection ( https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#indexing-mongoose-references ) in order to pull in all previous entries:

```
BookSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);

var Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
  , stream = TestSchema.synchronize()
  , count = 0;

stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
  count++;
});
stream.on('close', function(){
  console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents!');
});
stream.on('error', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

I get an error:

```
var TestSchema = mongoose.model('Test', Test)
           ^

ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined
```

Obviously, that's not going to work, sooooo I tried replacing `mongoose.model` with `keystone.list`...

```
stream = keystone.list('Test').synchronize();
```

But then I get a splurge of:

```
ReferenceError: Unknown keystone list {"paths":{"_id":{"path":"_id","instance":"ObjectID","validators":[],"setters":[null],"getters":[],"options":{"auto":true},"_index":null},"slug":{"enumValues":[],"regExp":null,"path":"slug","instance":"String","validators":[],"setters":[],"getters":[],"options":{"index":{"unique":true}},"_index":{"unique":true}},"createdAt":{"path":"createdAt"
```

Finished off with:

```
if (!ret) throw new ReferenceError('Unknown keystone list ' + JSON.stringify(arg));
                  ^

ReferenceError: Unknown keystone list "Test"
```

Seems like it should be simple... Anybody know what I'm missing? Please. Any help is greatly appreciated! Fanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize your data from `TestSchema` you should use:

`var stream = TestSchema.model.synchronize()`
or if you want get it from keystone list:

`var stream = keystone.list('Test').model.synchronize()`

What is important here you can call `sychronize` method only on model.

Hope this helps!